# Nethack keybord movement not working

Tags: nethack

I press 'y' and it says unknown command.  No numeric keypad here, and I need to move diagonally.  Is there an option to turn the normal nethack keyboard on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your nethack [options file](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Options) (its location depends on the system), you should set the [`number_pad`](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Options#number_pad) option to `0` to use the keys `hjklyubn` for movement. The line to set this option is

```
OPTIONS=number_pad:0
```